# "Summing" the series $\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{3}\sin(3x)+\frac{1}{4}\sin(4x)+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometric-series

"Summing" the series $\sin(x)+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)+\dfrac{1}{4}\sin(4x)+...$

Pose $$S=\sin(x)+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)+\dfrac{1}{4}\sin(4x)+...$$
$$C=\cos(x)+\dfrac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\cos(3x)+\dfrac{1}{4}\cos(4x)+...$$

$$C+iS = e^{ix}+\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{ix})^2+\dfrac{1}{3}(e^{ix})^3+\dfrac{1}{4}(e^{ix})^4+...$$

Let $t$ = $e^{ix}$

Then we have a series of $t+\dfrac{t}{2}+\dfrac{t}{3}+\dfrac{t}{4}+...=\log(1+t)$

Which is $-\log(1-e^{ix})=\log(1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x))$, use the formula $\log(A+iB)=\dfrac{1}{2}\log(A^2+B^2)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{B}{A}\right)$

$-\log([1-\cos(x)]-i\sin(x))=-\dfrac{1}{2}\log([1-\cos(x)]^2-i\sin^2(x))-i\arctan\left(-\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right))$. Since we are interested only in the imaginary part, we have the sum for $S$ is:

$$-\arctan\left(-\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)$$

Which is $-\arctan\left(-\cot(\dfrac{x}{2})\right)$

I don't know what to do next.

The "sum" of this series should be $\dfrac{\pi-x}{2}$, according to Euler.

Comment: I think your two formulae are the same. Consider a right angled triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and an acute angle $x/2$. Assume the sides are laid out so $\cot(x/2) = b/a$. Then $\tan(\pi/2 - x/2) = b/a$ by looking at the other angle.

Comment: $\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\frac x2\right)=\cot \frac x2$

Comment: the result is true for $x \in (0, 2\pi)$ not $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$ like in the alternating sum from the previous post; the substitution $x \to \pi-x$ proves it in $[0, \pi]$ from the alternating sum in the previous post and then same sends $[-\pi,0]$ to $[\pi, 2\pi]$ proving it there

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, I just check the identity. I need a serious revision of trig. I forgot too many identities. I left my notebook in my home country so I cannot consult it.

Comment: @Conrad, how do you know this conclusion. I am also perplexed by this summing technique. Euler didn't give the interval which this result hold, obviously due to "generality of algebra", so characteristic of XVIII century mathematics.

Comment: the alternating sum $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)-\dfrac{1}{4}\sin(4x)+...=x/2$ of your previous post is rigurously proved using the Fourier series of the odd function $x/2$ in $(-\pi, \pi)$ extended by periodicity to the line and by whatever value you want at the ends as it has a jump there (easy integration by parts checks Fourier coefficients are the given ones, general Fourier series theory for piecewise $C^1$ insures convergence except at ends); the substitution $x \to \pi-x$ sends $(-\pi, \pi)$ to $(0, 2\pi)$ hence the Fourier series here is valid precisely there

Comment: @Bumblebee I know this formula, isn't it a finite series?

Comment: @Bumblebee You mean take the limit as n reaching infinity?

Comment: @JamesWarthington: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

First, the series are
$$
\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}k
$$
and
$$
-\log(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k
$$
The series is $2\pi$-periodic and the sum for $-\pi\le x\le\pi$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}k
&=\frac1{2i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}k\\
&=-\frac1{2i}\left(\log(1-e^{ix})-\log(1-e^{-ix})\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-ix}}{1-e^{ix}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\log\left(-e^{-ix}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac\pi2-\frac x2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Note about $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}$**

Since $\sin(x)$ is odd, the series should be odd. However, $\frac{\pi-x}2$ is not odd. The limit as $x\to0^+$ is $\frac\pi2$, but at $x=0$, all the terms of the series are $0$, so the sum is $0$. So that should clue us into the fact that there is a discontinuity there (this is because the convergence is *not* uniform near $0$).

Taking the oddness into account we get $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac\pi2-\frac x2$. This is also shown by looking at $\frac1{2i}\log\left(-e^{-ix}\right)$: when $x$ is increasing from $0$, $-e^{-ix}$ is moving clockwise from $-1$; thus, $\frac1{2i}\log\left(-e^{-ix}\right)$ is decreasing from $\frac\pi2$. When $x$ is decreasing from $0$, $-e^{-ix}$ is moving counter-clockwise from $-1$; thus, $\frac1{2i}\log\left(-e^{-ix}\right)$ is increasing from $-\frac\pi2$.